# Why don't we use nuclear fission to generate the necessary temperatures needed for nuclear fusion?

Tags: nuclear-engineering

We can control the energy generated by nuclear fission by limiting the amount of neutrons release. Those extremely high temperatures will be more than sufficient to incite a nuclear fusion process.

Answer (score 5):

This is exactly how hydrogen bombs work: a fission bomb is used to "light the fuse" on the fusion process.

Using fission to generate the pressures, temperatures and densities required to initiate a fusion process also causes the prompt destruction of the immediate surroundings, which in this case would include the power plant in which the fusion process was supposed to take place. This is because the power output of the fission *primary* is designed to symmetrically surround the fusion *secondary*. While the secondary is being violently compressed, a large percentage of the primary energy output is pointed the wrong way (symmetrically outwards) and destroys anything in its path.